# Что в моем решении не так?

Tags: javascript

Только начал изучать javascript. Сломал голову над задачкой от sololearn. В чем мои ошибки?

Данная программа должна высчитать годовой доход по займу.
Она должна соответствующим образом использовать в качестве вводных данных сумму займа и годовую процентную ставку, а затем создать заем в качестве объекта.
Завершите функцию вне конструктора для расчета годового дохода, после этого закрепите это значение за соответствующим полем (вам также необходимо его создать) конструктора для получения результата.

Пример вводных данных

```
15000
20
```

Пример результата

```
3000
```

Пояснение
Результат – это годовой доход по займу, где первоначальная сумма равна 15 000, а 20% - годовая процентная ставка: 20/100*15000 = 3000.

В конструкторе вы должны создать новое свойство для хранения возвращаемого из вычислительной функции значения дохода за год.

Вот одно из моих решений:

```js
function main() {
  //получите первоначальную сумму и процент
  var amount = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
  var yearPercent = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

  var loan1 = new Loan(amount, yearPercent);

  //вывод результата в консоль
  console.log(loan1.yearIncome());
}

function Loan(amount, percent) {
  this.amount = amount;
  this.yearPercent = percent;
  //введите код сюда
  this.yearIncome = calcYearIncome;
};

function calcYearIncome() {
  //завершите функцию для вычисления годового дохода
  var yearIncome = yearPercent / 100 * amount;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

чем вам не нравится такое решение (если уж используем современные JS)?

```
class Loan
{
    constructor(amount, percent) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.yearPercent = percent;     
    }
    
    calcYearIncome() {
        return this.yearPercent / 100 * this.amount;
    }
}

let obj = new Loan(15000, 20);

console.log(obj.calcYearIncome());
```

P.S.

чтобы ваш код работал, его надо переделать в такой:

```
function Loan(amount, percent) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.yearPercent = percent;
    //введите код сюда
    this.yearIncome = calcYearIncome(amount, percent);
};

function calcYearIncome(amount, yearPercent){
    //завершите функцию для вычисления годового дохода
    return yearPercent / 100 * amount;
}

let loan = new Loan(15000, 20);

console.log(loan.yearIncome);
```

P.P.S.

в вашем же коде есть проблемы тут:

```
this.yearIncome = calcYearIncome;
```

Вы в переменную записываете указатель на функцию, а не значение функции. Это можно было бы делать, но тогда вам надо было бы ее вызывать потом так:

```
loan.yearIncome(x, y)
```

но вот `x`, `y` взять то неоткуда, поэтому такой метод не подходит

И вот тут проблема:

```
function calcYearIncome(){
    //завершите функцию для вычисления годового дохода
    var yearIncome = yearPercent / 100 * amount;
}``
```

функции неоткуда брать переменные `yearPercent`, `amount`, а результат `yearIncome` никуда не сохраняется и остается внутри функции